# Как спрятать служебную функцию?

Tags: c++

Я пишу библиотеку, все классы которой лежат в одном неймспейсе. Мне нужно определить служебную функцию, которая будет вызываться только классами моей библиотеки и никогда не будет вызываться за её пределами. Но при этом я не могу положить её в анонимный неймспейс или пометить как `static` ибо вызывающие её классы находятся в различных единицах трансляции.

В общем, разыскивается аналог C# `internal`, но для C++. Что посоветуете?

Так же готов выслушать критику оправданности такого сокрытия в целом. Ибо служебная функция не может нарушить целостность какого-либо класса и её сокрытие является скорее вопросом хорошего стиля.

Comment: Вообще то в с++ принято делать классы. И, соответственно, приватные методы.

Comment: Можно просто вставить ее в private static каждого класса который ее вызывает и размножить определение в каждом файле, конечно это китайский вариант, плюс в том что он предельно прост. Перед тем как копировать стоит окончательно оттестировать её.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Либо отметьте ее как `private static` в специальном классе, и дайте другим классам доступ через `friend,` либо просто создайте специальный `namespace` с названием `detail` и разместите в нем эту функцию.

> Boost, например, [использует второй вариант.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/boost/detail/none_t.hpp)

- По поводу оправданности - действительно есть такие функции, которые имеет смысл переиспользовать, однако только в контексте какого-то модуля. То есть, если вы точно знаете, что эту функцию запрещено использовать извне, то, собственно говоря, от `detail` в таком случае никуда не деться.

> Другое дело, что обычно можно превратить такого рода функции во вполне себе солидные `helper` методы, которые можно сделать публичными и оттестировать из другого модуля (если в этом есть необходимость).

- `internal` в C# полезен исключительно в контексте работы со сборками, поэтому, естественно, что в C++ нет его прямого аналога.

Comment: Разве вариант с ``detail`` ограничивает доступ из вне? Всмысле сторонний разработчик может использовать функции их этого пространства имен.

Comment: @fogbit Может, но не должен по контракту. А что там происходит в случае нарушения контракта нас, в общем-то, не должно волновать.

Comment: Т.е. это просто договоренность разработчиков библиотеки?

Comment: IMHO в этом обсуждении все понимают, что при большом желании можно вызвать любую (даже static) функцию.

Answer (score 7):

Боюсь, обычную функцию так просто не спрячешь.

Можно ее объявить как private static метод какого-нибудь класса, затем в этом классе указать дружественные функции и классы, из которых она может вызываться. Примерно так:

```
#priv_func.h
class B;
void ff();
.....  Здесь список объявлений  всех друзей
class AA {
   friend void ff();
   friend class B;
   ........
   private:
     static void priv_func() {
        std::cout << "Private" << std::endl;
     }

};
```

Все это оформляется в виде хедера, который далее вставляется где нужно.

Функция вызывается очень просто

```
AA::priv_func();
```